# ionic modal remove and animation is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic modal in which once i open the ionic modal and submit the button the ionic remove model is not working as well as even the animation is not working in the modal.I have tried using ionic hide instead of remove but still it is not working can anyone tell me what is the issue in ionic modal.

Modal:

```
'use strict';
(function () {
      angular.module('main')
     .service('ModalService', ModalService);
     ModalService.$inject = ['$ionicModal', '$log'];
     function ModalService ($ionicModal, $log) {
    var init = function (tpl, $scope) {
      var promise;
      var a = $scope;
      $scope = a;

      promise = $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(tpl, {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-right'
      }).then(function (modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
        return modal;
      });

      $scope.openModal = function () {
        $log.log('openModal function got clicked', $scope);
        $scope.modal.show();
      };

      $scope.closeModal = function () {
        $scope.modal.hide();
      };

      $scope.removeModal = function () {
        $scope.modal.remove();
      };

      $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $scope.modal.remove();
      });

      return promise;
    };

    return {
      init: init
    };
  }
})();
```

Controller to call the ionic remove and hide:

```
function modalFunction (htmlpath) {
  vm.modalListType = 'category';
  ModalService
    .init(htmlpath, $scope)
    .then(function (modal) {
      $log.log('modal success');
      catModal = modal;
      catModal.show();
      vm.search = '';
    });
}

function closeModal () {
  catModal.hide();
}

function removeModal () {
  $log.log('removeModal got called', catModal);
  catModal.remove();
}
```

Html file :

```
<div class="center-align">
      <button class="button trans-but m-t-10" type="submit" ng-click="vm.addProduct()">{{'save_message' | translate}}</button>
    </div>
```

Function which call the remove function:

```
function addProduct () {
  $log.log('addProduct called: ', vm.product);
  var data = [];
  data.push({field: vm.product.type, type: 'text', name: $translate.instant('{{"producttype_message" | translate}}')});
  data.push({field: vm.product.count, type: 'num', amounttype: 'Advance', name: $translate.instant('{{"ecount_message" | translate}}')});
  data.push({field: vm.product.rate, type: 'num', amounttype: 'Advance', name: $translate.instant('{{"eprice_message" | translate}}')});
  CommonService.validate(data).then(function () {
    //vm.product.total = (vm.product.count - vm.product.deduction) * vm.product.rate;
    vm.products.push(vm.product);
    closeModal();
    removeModal();
  }, function (err) {
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close();
    CommonService.toast(err);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to close the modal with the function, `$scope.modal.hide();`
Since if you use `remove()`, you will have to create the modal again.

A possible solution could be:

```
function closeModal () {
  $scope.modal.hide();
}
```

Or

```
function closeModal () {
  $scope.modal.remove();
}
```

This would be inside your modalFunction controller.